# Swift Change EditButton()

Tags: swift, styles, edit

is there a Way to change the look of the swift

```
EditButton()
```

like:

```
  EditButton(){
                    label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .padding(.top)
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }
```

or do i need any Workaround / an own Editbutton?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it out:
Works as seen here:
[SwiftUI change EditButton Text Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301381/swiftui-change-editbutton-text-color)
In my Case:

```
var editButton: some View {
   return Button {
       if editMode == .inactive {
           editMode = .active
       } else {
           editMode = .inactive
       }
   } label: {
       Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
       .padding(.top)
       .font(.title)
       .foregroundColor(Color.red)
   }
}
```

Comment: If another answer answers your question please close your question as a duplicate.